# How to select first 10 values from database and store it In PHP vars

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3, flash

I have database table named: "Eurokos" and here are 2 columns "name" and "time".
I need to make TOP 10 players table in php, who passed game fastest, this mean I need to take lowest time.

To insert data to database I used MySQLi, to select I need to use the same? I've tried 
`$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_db","pass","my_db");
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM eurokos e ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 5"))`

Could you help me? I don't know how to echo It, how to store it in vars?
Best way if possible would be, get "Top 10" players, get It in php and send to Action Script.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
I use this code in action script, but It doesn't work. How I finally can print answer (not trace)? I need help with `myButton` usage. I see here not printing `_message = myXml.user.*; message_txt.text = _message;`

```
var myXml:XML;

function uploadTops():void
{
    var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    myLoader.load(new URLRequest("top.php"));
    myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
}
function processXML(e:Event):void {
myXml = new XML(e.target.data);
trace(myXml);
}
function myButton(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    uploadTops();
//  _message = myXml.user.*;
//  message_txt.text = _message;
}
```

I got error: `Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.` when trying to trace

```
at MemoryGame/processXML()[C:\Users\Petras\Downloads\geraseaa\geraseaa\gerase\MemoryGame.as:570]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_db","pass","my_db");
    $query = "SELECT name,time FROM eurokos ORDER by time DESC LIMIT 10";

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    echo '<results>';
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo '<user name="'.$row["name"].'" time="'.$row["time"].'" />';
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    echo '</results>';
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

That will output an XML document that you can load and read in AS :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <results>
    <user name="someone" time="xxx" />
    <user name="someone" time="xxx" />
    [...]
</results>
```

XML is created on the fly every time you call the PHP script from AS.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but when i created php file as your example, when I use It, I don't get any output and xml file isn't created, also I don't get any errors. What wrong I do?

Comment: The script works (check source or console, as I said the XML is created "on the fly" so there is no file...) so the problem is in the query which dont get results in your db. Check the query and adapt it to your table (in your other question, the "name" was called userName...).

Comment: Thanks, really It is userName, i changed this, but the same file doesn't work, I mean if here is `echo '<user name="'.$row["userName"].'" time="'.$row["time"].'" />';` It must be printed out on php which I use now, true?

Comment: My connection to database info really good, table `eurokos` and 2 columns `userName` and `time`, as I understand everything with this info is ok, so what's wrong?

Comment: Ah It is hidden, when I use "inspect element" I can see that info is printed, but hidden. 
And how you said I can call that XML with AS3?

Comment: Problem is that you store time as text, try to order ASC instead of DESC but it would have been better to store it under INT format. There are plenty of tutorials to learn how to load / read XML in AS3, for example http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/

Comment: I have 1 more question for you in this step: `var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("oman3d.xml"));` I need to know xml file name, if my xml is "on the fly" as you said, how can I get It on Action Script?

Comment: use the php file name, i.e: "oman3d.php" request will invoke php file, php file will return xml data.

Comment: **Warning**: Do not forget checking the connection and then the query status for failures. +1 anyway for @RafH...

Comment: Thank you for answer, I updated my question with AS code, could you help me a little bit more?